# Best practices for AWS SDK clients lifecycle in Javascript

Tags: aws-sdk

We've encountered an issue in production using AWS SDK v3 for Javascript where one of the DynamoDB Client would timeout and never recover.

This lead us to think about the SDK clients lifecycle. [It's explicitly mentioned in the Java SDK that clients are supposed to be long lived for performance optimisation.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/creating-clients.html#client-lifecycle)

> Service clients in the SDK are thread-safe and, for best performance,
> you should treat them as long-lived objects

Is it the same for the Javascript SDK v3? Should we keep the clients around as long-lived objects? How can we recover from a timeout or prevent them?

Answer (score 0):

These types of clients take a while to get initialized, and creating them makes the device work noticeably harder than usual. Creating them uses a measurable amount of system resources.

They are not sacred cows. If they get messed up for any reason, recycle them. Otherwise, you might cache them locally between uses.